# How to import catia assembly to Matlab. Simmechanics

Tags: matlab

In catia .stl format is available only for part file not for assembly file. Please help how to import asembly in simmechanics

.CATProduct to .stl
Or Is there any other way to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An STL file converts a solid model to an approximation that is represented by a bunch of triangular faces. There is no way for an STL file to represent joints or any other motion constraints because it's simply not part of the file protocol.

This means that, if your assembly has motion constraints or movable parts that you *don't* actually want to export that assembly to one STL file. Instead, you should export each part individually and then re-build the assembly in SimMechanics using the frame transforms and motion constraint blocks provided there.

I understand that this can be a (very) painful and tedious process, but unfortunately [SimMechanics only supports SolidWorks, Inventor, and Pro/E](http://www.mathworks.com/help/physmod/sm/ref/smimport.html)  (stated in the tip at the bottom of the page).

That said, if you're using SimMechanics, I'd say there's a fair bet you're a student (because SimMechanics is EXPENSIVE given the perquisites) and Autodesk Inventor is free to students.

If your model is only a few parts, it will probably be easiest to just reassemble it with the joint constraints. If it's especially detailed, you might be better off fusing the non-moving parts for a "simulation model" such that you do wind up with only a few parts. If you absolutely need to import an assembly that has a lot (probably over 10 would be a lot to me) of parts or you intend on importing models frequently then I would pursue acquiring Inventor or SolidWorks. SolidWorks is better but not free to students, but they have an education version that is less expensive than the commercial version.